# OracleDBConsole cant start after restarting windows

Tags: windows-xp, oracle11g

I have **`Oracle11Gr2`** installed on virtual **`WindowsXP Sp3`** with **`VMWare Player`**.

Just after the installation of Oracle, the console service `OracleDBConsole` starts and I can access the em console at `https://testlaptop:1158/em/` .

But after restarting the virtual machine the service cant start and when i start it using  `emctl start dbconsole` i get error  the service cant start.

when i reconfigure the database

```
emca -deconfig dbcontrol db -repos drop
SET ORACLE_HOSTNAME = testlaptop 
SET ORACLE_UNQNAME=testdb
emca -config dbcontrol db -repos recreate
```

the service starts but when i restart the vm it cant start again i get the same error.

Plz help me, I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is simple, you have to **unplug the network cable** and start the console service ( you have to do it every time you want to start the console)

```
emctl start dbconsole
```

if console still not starting then recreate it:

**1.** start the listener

```
lsnrctl start
```

**2.** remove the console

```
cd %ORACLE_HOME%/ora11gr2/bin
emca -deconfig dbcontrol db -repos drop
```

NB: *it may take up to 30mn, be patient*

**3.** recreate the console

```
set oracle_unqname = TESTDB
set ORACLE_HOSTNAME = MYPC
emca -config dbcontrol db -repos recreate
```

*be patient it may take long time too.*

**4.** now unplug the network cable and start the console service, it should start

if it does not or if it start but you cant login, then

**a.** verify that windows time zone is the same as oracle time zone defined in

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\ora11gr2\MYPC_testdb\sysman\config\emd.properties  
at line **agentTZRegion=GMT**
```

to know witch timezone code to use, run this:

```
SELECT * FROM v$timezone_names where upper(TZNAME) like '%MAURITANIA%';
```

Replace Mauritania by your country.

**b.** enable system account

```
alter user system account unlock;
```

**c.** unplug the network cable and start the console service again.

I hope this helps, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a `VM` on a W2003 server and resolved it by editing the `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file

- add the `hostname` to the own `IP` address. In my case:

  ```
  192.168.5.139     oraserver
  ```
- Save this file (beware, read only file, give `NTFS` permissions first)
- Reboot the server.